# Google Apps Script - Event object not 'Typed'

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, triggers

The code fragment:

```
function doGet(e) {
  Logger.log('hi '+e);
}
```

yields:
[18-05-26 07:38:14:290 AEST] hi [object Object]
The properties of e (eg source) are therefore undefined

Comment: You want to know the keys and values of ``[object Object]``. If my understanding is correct, how about modifying to ``Logger.log('hi '+ JSON.stringify(e))``?

Comment: How are you calling that code?

Comment: @Rubén In the case of ``hi [object Object]``, when the deployed Web Apps is called for the endpoint, it can be retrieved. The type of ``e`` is "object". If ``doGet(e)`` is directly run, ``hi undefined`` is returned. The type of ``e`` is "undefined". By the way, if OP simply uses ``Logger.log(e)``, the parsed object can be also seen when the deployed Web Apps is called.

Comment: Log it in Stackdriver. Interactive log, persists for a month

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your kind comment. My previous comment was pointed to the OP and my intention was to let him know that the question is unclear without downvoting his first question.

Comment: @Rubén Oh, I'm sorry. Thank you for letting me know. I had misunderstand about it.

Comment: Thank you (@Tanaikke esp) for your comments.

Comment: Here is the stringified event:

[18-05-28 04:52:37:961 AEST] hi {"parameter":{},"contextPath":"","contentLength":-1,"queryString":"","parameters":{}}